# Enclosing two divs within single div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is  my code below,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(function() {
        $("#image,#image1").draggable();

            $('#clickme').click(function(){

                $("#image,#image1").wrapAll("<div id='newimage'/>");
            });
        });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myimage" style="display:block;border:2px solid green;">
        <div id="image" style="display:block;">
            stack
        </div>
        <div id="image1" style="display:block;">
            is the best
        </div>
    </div>

   <span id="clickme">click me</span>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see on the above code... divs `image` and `image1` are draggable, after I click on `click me`, both the divs will be enclosed inside an other div with the id `newimage` …till here its working fine… but the problem is with the css style .. i want "new image" div to hold both "image" and "image1" ..in your example its hold only one div ............It should be something like this... "image" width is 50px.."image1" width is 50px and the distance between them is 30px(after dragging) ... so the total height of the "newimage" should be 130px... it should not take 100% width as "body" ...if someone look at it.. he should know  both are "stack" and "is the best" are in same block(new image) ...

output should come something like this after dragging both "image" and "image1" divs...

[image]

Comment: you need to manage css as if the the wrapper is changed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done changes in code.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AvTm/)

```
$(function() {
$("#image,#image1").draggable();

$('#clickme').click(function(){

    $("#image,#image1").wrapAll("<div id='newimage'/>");
    var w1 = $('#image').width();
    var w2= $('#image1').width();
    var pos1 = $('#image').position().left + w1; 
    var pos2 = $('#image1').position().left;
    var diffBtTwo = pos1 > pos2 ? pos1 - pos2 : pos2 - pos1;   
    var total = w1 + w2 + diffBtTwo + 20;
    var height = $('#image').position().top + $('#image1').position().top + 20;     
    $('#newimage').css('height',height);
    $('#newimage').css('width',total);


 });
});
```

Comment: @Friend If still you want anything else just mention your requirement

Comment: Got It @Chinnu Thank you... I like your Name "Chinnu" :)